# object tag with svg populated with entire webpage

Tags: html, css, svg, vue.js, icons

I'm trying to include an svg icon into my personal portfolio with the **object** tag(need to be animated). This is what happens when I do so: 
[Entire webpage populated within object tag for some reason.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flUGm.png)

My entire webpage gets shoved inside the object tag. I'm using Vuejs, here is a snippet of my template:

```
<template>
  <div>    
    <p>Landing Page</p>
    <object 
      type="image/svg+xml"
      data="public/Images/logo/logo.svg" 
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

Any idea why this behaviour is occuring?

Comment: I guess you have the code before the starting html tag try to move it down

Comment: This behaviour is probably because that URL returns a 404, which the webpack dev server redirects to your `index.html`. Try stripping the `public/` part of the URL. If you are using a 3.0 cli template, the contents of `public` folder are copied into the root, so there is no need to specify `public/`.

Comment: Can't you directly inline your SVG? Something like [this](http://calebporzio.com/using-inline-svgs-in-vue-compoments/). This way you can animate your logo as you want.

Comment: @yuriy636 thank you, getting rid of public/ solved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

You could include your svg as an image instead

```
<img src="public/Images/logo/test.svg" />
```

Comment: The icon needs to be interactive, so I will need the object tag here.